# Check if JPA entity exists without loading it

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, eclipselink

The problem is following.

We have a server endpoint, that receives feedback from clients. Feedback received in multipart/form-based format, with fields:

```
ProductId - product identifier
Message - feedback message
Log_file - attached log file
Screenshot - attached screenshot file
```

Server code first checks if the product with given id exists and if not - closes connection without receiving any attached files.

We use Eclipselink JPA to store product objects.

How it's possible to check if a product with given id exists without loading it from underlying database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `count` to see if any row with the id will be returned.

```
em.createQuery(
    "SELECT COUNT(b.productId) 
    FROM Products b WHERE b.productId=:productId"
);
```

If `count < 1` there is no product with that id.
Else there is a product with that id.

Comment: Counting is just unnecessary when all you need to check is if there are any records at all that match a condition, instead we could just select a constant, for e.g., 
`SELECT 1 
    FROM Products b WHERE b.productId=:productId`

Comment: @aathif No, it is not necessarily. Retrieving your result by ```.getSingleResult()``` you want to be sure to always retrieve a result. ```SELECT 1``` does not give any result in case the DB cannot find any record with that id. You will run into ```javax.persistence.NoResultException: getSingleResult() did not retrieve any entities```. Of course you could then handle this exception instead - but is this clean code?

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to avoid exactly?  JPA allows lazy loading of pretty much every field in the entity, so what you get back may or may not be loaded.  A simple EntityManager.find operation will retrieve the entity from the cache if it exists there, and if not, check the database, so for most situations this might be enough.  If it goes to the database, it will then build an instance and put it in the cache, but that instance will only include eager mappings.

Otherwise, you can avoid the loading using any JPA query that returns data rather than an entity instance, but this will require a database hit.  The count option above is one way, but a simple "Select e.id from Employee e where e.id =:empId" will work as well.

Comment: Thank you! We need to minimize request validation overhead.